# How to return new value every time when function is called

Tags: javascript

I have an array with some words there. I want to write a function which returns first value from array when function is called, but when function is called second time it returns second value, third time third value, when values ends in array, function returns undefined. Like:

```
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

function getValue() {
...
}

getValue() \\ return text1;
getValue() \\ return text2;
getValue() \\ return text3;
getValue() \\ return undefined;
getValue() \\ return undefined;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold a counter which is incremented on every call. Once it's after the end of the array, the function will return undefined

```
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
let i = 0;
function getValue() {
  return arr[i++];
}

getValue() // return text1;
getValue() // return text2;
getValue() // return text3;
getValue() // return undefined;
getValue() // return undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `splice` method.

> The splice() method adds and/or removes array elements.

```
function getValue() {
 const element = arr[0];
 arr.splice(0,1); // At first position remove one element
 return element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a a quick and dirty solution, which **pollutes!** the global scope (context):

```js
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
let idx = 0;
function getValue() {
  return arr[idx++];
}

console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
```

Each execution context has a link to its outside world. So the execution context of `getValue` has access to variable `idx` (in this case global variable, because it is defined in the global scope). The outer environment (world) depends where the function is defined lexically (where it is written).

**Better solution:**

To not pollute the global scope you could switch to a higher order function (a function which returns a function)

```js
function createGetValueFunction() {
  const arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
  let idx = 0;

  return function getValue() {
    return arr[idx++];
  };
}

const getValue = createGetValueFunction();
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
console.log(getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a counter variable outside of the method as so:

```
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

let ind = 0
    function getValue() {
    if(ind < arr.length){
        console.log(arr[ind]);
    }
    else{
        console.log("undefined")
    }
    ind+=1;
}

getValue() 
getValue() 
getValue() 
getValue() 
getValue()
```

Comment: You don't need the check for the length, because in js it's safe to access index out of bounds. It will just return undefined

Comment: True, but in case OP wanted to make the return message unique, this works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use an varibale to manage the number of calls, and return undefined if number of calls is large than array length:

```js
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
let index = 0;

function getValue() {
  if(index >= arr.length) return undefined;
  return arr[index++];
}

console.log(getValue())
console.log(getValue())
console.log(getValue())
console.log(getValue())
console.log(getValue())
```

Comment: Your length check is wrong and unnecessary. Wrong because you need to check `index>=arr.length` and unnecessary, because in js it is safe to access non existent indexes, it will just return undefined

Answer (score 1):

I would say make sure that the function is keeping track of the position that you're looking at.

example:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
let pos = 0;

function test(arr) {
  if(arr[pos]) {
    pos++;
    return(arr[pos - 1])
  };  
  
  if(!arr[pos]) {
    return(undefined);
  };
};

console.log(test(array));
console.log(test(array));
console.log(test(array));
console.log(test(array));
console.log(test(array));
console.log(test(array));
```

Maybe something like this.
Here I'm keeping track of the position, so I always know what position I need my function to be looking at. Then, I add 1 to the value so it knows to switch to the next element in the array. To be honest, I spent maybe about two seconds on this and there might be a much better way to do this. This is also something I feel would be easier to keep track of in a class of some sort.

Comment: Seems quite counterintuitive, to first increment the `pos` and then access `arr[pos-1]`. Furthermore, your approach will return `undefined` on the first call instead of `0` for `const arr= [0]`

Comment: @derpirscher wait first part I get, but the second part I'm not understanding. wdym when you say that it'll return undefined on the first call instead of 0?

Comment: Because if `arr[pos] == 0` then `if(!arr[pos])` will be `true` (because `0` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)) and thus `return undefined` will be executed. So your code will return `undefined` for any position in the array, containing the value `0`. And furthermore, it won't increase the `pos` in that case, you you will be stuck at that index forever, even if there are still elements in the array. Just try it and set `array = [1,2,3,0,4,5]` in your code  ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using IE, you can use [`Generator Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to create such functionality, as followings:

```js
let arr = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

function* arrayIterator(index) {
  while (index < arr.length) {
    yield arr[index];
    index++;
  }
}

const getValue = arrayIterator(0)

console.log(getValue.next().value)
console.log(getValue.next().value)
console.log(getValue.next().value)
```